# How to genrerate a network file from a non network file?

Tags: data-visualization, cytoscape

I have an input file that look like :

```
ID  Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3  Attribute4  Attribute5  Attribute6
1   UNIQ1-1     Common2-1   UNIQ3-1     UNIQ3-1     UNIQ5-1     UNIQ6-1
2   UNIQ1-2     Common2-1   UNIQ3-2     UNIQ3-2     UNIQ5-2     UNIQ6-2
```

And I would like to obtain a source/target file like :

```
Source  Target
1       UNIQ1-1
UNIQ1-1 Common2-1
Common2-1   UNIQ3-1
UNIQ3-1 UNIQ3-1
UNIQ3-1 UNIQ5-1
UNIQ5-1 UNIQ6-1
2       UNIQ1-2
UNIQ1-2 Common2-1
Common2-1   UNIQ3-2
UNIQ3-2 UNIQ3-2
UNIQ3-2 UNIQ5-2
UNIQ5-2 UNIQ6-2
```

Should I use an external tool or is it doable directly in Cytoscape or in another network visualisation tool?  The goal is to higlight common denominator in large data files.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do this directly in Cytoscape, but it would be somewhat labor intensive.  You would need to repeatedly read in the file selecting the first and second columns as source and target the first time, then the second and third columns, etc.  In the end, you'll wind up with a series of "strings", where each string represents a row in your table.

I suspect a much easier way to do this would be to use RCy3 or py2Cytoscape and simply open your file in R or python and then inject it into Cytoscape that way.

-- scooter

Comment: I used a shell script. That does the job but that is very very slow.